# Connect to mysql database from a PHP file

Tags: mysql, php, database

I have created a form which takes input from user and will feed it to MYSQL database. I have used the following command

```
$servername = 'localhost';
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $dbname = 'asthana2';

        //creating connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

However there's an error popping up that

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

What can i do to fix this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had also this problem... As far as I know, this is because the *root* user cannot be used without a password (security reasons). To work around this error, you have to assign a password to the root user.

How to do this, you can read [here](https://www.tecmint.com/connect-to-mysql-without-root-password/amp/)

I would, however, create a new user and give them the rights where this user needs. Because I would never access the database with the root user (too many rights, too powerful).

Answer (score 0):

mysql -u root -p 
Then enter your password
type this command
update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;

Comment: root password will be empty after this for mysql

Comment: Please do not use comments to extend your answer.  It is better to edit your post to include all relevant advice (then delete your comment).  Please also "code format" the code that you are recommending (highlight text then press Ctrl+K; or use the editor tool's code formatting icon; or wrap the text with backticks).